# Click outside div and icon, div hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-right">
  <img class="menu-icon" src="images/menu-icon.jpg" alt="menu">
  <div class="menu-drop">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$("header .menu-icon").click(function() {
  $(".menu-drop").slideToggle();
});
```

CSS:

```
.menu-drop {
  display: none;
}
```

I want when click outside `.menu-drop` and `.menu-icon` then `.menu-drop` div hide
when clicking menu-drop div it will stay not hide.

Comment: try using `not` from jquery. https://api.jquery.com/not/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On document click, you can check whether the clicked element has the specific class or not, if it does not have the class `slideUp()` the menu. You also have to prevent the event propagation on clicking the menu.

```js
$(".menu-icon").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(".menu-drop").slideToggle();
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
  if(!$(e.target).hasClass('menu-right') && !($(e.target).hasClass('menu-drop')|| $(e.target).parents('.menu-drop').hasClass('menu-drop'))){
    $(".menu-drop").slideUp();
  }
});
```

```css
.menu-drop {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-right">
  <img class="menu-icon" src="images/menu-icon.jpg" alt="menu">
  <div class="menu-drop">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when click menu-drop, this hide. menu-drop will stay when clicking menu-drop

Answer (score 1):

Use `mouseup` with `document` like below.

```js
const $menu = $('.menu-icon, .menu-drop');
$(document).mouseup(e => {
  if (!$menu.is(e.target) &&
    $menu.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $(".menu-drop").hide();
  }
});

$('.menu-icon').on('click', () => {
  $(".menu-drop").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.menu-drop {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-right">
  <img class="menu-icon" src="images/menu-icon.jpg" alt="menu">
  <div class="menu-drop">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a [brief caution](https://dmitripavlutin.com/when-not-to-use-arrow-functions-in-javascript/#2-callback-functions-with-dynamic-context) about using fat arrow syntax in event listeners

Comment: when click menu-drop, this hide. menu-drop will stay when clicking menu-drop.

Answer (score 0):

Here some modification

```js
$(".menu-icon").click(function(e) { 
  $(".menu-drop").slideDown();
});

$(document).on('click', function (e) {
  if(!$(e.target).hasClass('menu-icon'))
    $(".menu-drop").slideUp();
});
```

```css
.menu-drop {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-right">
  <img class="menu-icon" src="images/menu-icon.jpg" alt="menu">
  <div class="menu-drop">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when click menu-drop, this hide. menu-drop will stay when clicking menu-drop

Answer (score 0):

Use a single event listener on the body. Query the event target and show and hid the menu as required.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /*Add event listener to document*/
  $(document).click(function(event) {
    //If the target is the icon, toggle the menu
    console.log(event.target);
    console.log($(event.target).closest(".menu-drop").length)
    if(event.target.matches(".menu-icon"))
    {
      $(".menu-drop").slideToggle();
    }
    //Otherwise if outside the menu, slide up
    else if($(event.target).closest(".menu-drop").length === 0 )
    {
      $(".menu-drop").slideUp();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.menu-drop {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-right">
  <img class="menu-icon" src="images/menu-icon.jpg" alt="menu">
  <div class="menu-drop">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when click menu-drop, this hide. menu-drop will stay when clicking menu-drop

Comment: @MohibulHasan answer updated, needed to count for parent